# apache httpd.conf setting for chinese domain

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a chinese domain to host.  I setup the DNS part and working fine.

However, I cannot set it up in Apache.  I did add the alias but still not working.

```
<VirtualHost 202.64.x.x:80>
ServerName aaaa.com:80
DocumentRoot /var/www/aaaa/
ServerAlias XN--aaaaaaaaaaaa.XN--aaaaaaa
```

Do I need to add the chinese domain name in Alias?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A virtualhost setup would be like this, so no port 80 in the servername, plus a closing tag! You need to restart Apache after editing this. Use the proper vhost file to edit this, not the config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.xn
    ServerAdmin test@test.xn
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.xn 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have the closing tag in the file just didn't put that in the example.  all other alias are working but not this chinese domain only.  Adding :80 at ServerName does not affect the result as all other domains work this way too.